# Book where the characters could wear a contraption on their head that would allow them to experience recordings of other peoples lives

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book more than 30 years ago, so it's older sci fi. In the book, the characters could wear a contraption on their head that would allow them to experience recordings of other peoples lives.  There was a food shortage, so people would be able to eat "kibble" for free, but it was a last resort. I thought the title was something like "Little Gods", but I can't find a book with anything like that in the title.

Comment: One of these, perhaps; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=little+gods&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: It's not Little Gods by Tim Pratt. That's about a guy whose wife dies

Comment: It's not Little Gods by Holly Black. That's about a wiccan girl named Ellory

Comment: It's not Little Gods by Neal F. Litherland. That's about a 'Warlock-for-hire' called Blackheart

Comment: It just could be *Mother of Storms* by John Barnes (1994). It takes place in a dystopic future where climate change brought widespread famine and chaos. I seem to remember that there were emergency distribution of protein analogue - I am not sure whether it was called kibble or not.

Comment: Although I haven't seen the film myself, the recordings remind me of Strange Days. Maybe this is relevant: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TransferableMemory?from=Main.TanksForTheMemories

Comment: Except for the "kibble" aspect it sounds a lot like Spider Robinson's "Mind Killer".  https://www.amazon.com/Mindkiller-Spider-Robinson/dp/0441532993

Comment: It's probably _[Beyond the Blue Event Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_the_Blue_Event_Horizon)_ by Frederik Pohl, the followup to _Gateway_. Or _Heechee Rendezvous_, the third book, where the things from BtBEH are ubiquitous.

Comment: Another question: Did you read this in English? Sometimes titles of translations can be **very** different from the original...

Comment: There's also a small amount of similarity to *Brainstorm*, Natalie Wood's last movie appearance.  No "kibble" in that, but full-sensory recording and playback was at the core...

Answer (score 5):

Thus is a long shot, but could it be [Little Heroes by Norman Spinrad](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1626)? It was published in 1987 so it fits your time frame.

The book is set in a dystopian near future where social inequality has become extreme. The people at the bottom end get handouts of free kibble (it's called "kibble" in the book).

There are addicts called *wireheads* who use a kind of helmet that plays back recordings of other lives. It's used as a form of escapism, allowing them to experience lifestyles that they'll never experience in real life.

The reason I think this is a long shot is because the kibble eating and wireheads are only a small part of the novel. The book heavily involves the rock music industry, and it doesn't shy away from some of the seamier aspects of that life and the language used to describe it. If this was the book I would have thought you'd remember the more violent aspects rather than a few background details.